# Error executing an action in kanban odoo 11 view with custom module

Tags: xml, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

In ODOO 11 I have a custom module with the FORM view and the TREE view, however, I am now trying to make the KANBAN view that when programming the ACTIONS of execution it throws me an error. Could you help me what is happening with the action?

Error message:

```
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 1332, in xmlid_lookup
    raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: employee_car_request.action_all_customers" while parsing /odoo/custom/addons/employee_car_request/views/views.xml:95, near
<record id="action_all_customers_kanban" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_all_customers"/>
            <field name="view_id" ref="kanban_all_customers"/>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban</field>
            <field name="sequence">17</field>
        </record>
```

This is to do a KANBAN view in ODOO 11 Comunity version on Ubuntu Server, the model is: car.request

views.xml, to model: employee_car_request

```
      <record id="kanban_all_customers" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="model">car.request</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                        <kanban>
                                <field name="name" />
                                <field name="date_from" />
                                        <templates>
                                                <t t-name="kanban-box">
                                                        <div class="oe_kanban_card">
                                                                <field name="name" />
                                                        </div>
                                                </t>
                                        </templates>
                        </kanban>
                </field>
        </record>

        <record id="action_all_customers_kanban" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
                <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_all_customers" />
                <field name="view_id" ref="kanban_all_customers" />
                <field name="view_mode">kanban</field>
                <field name="sequence">17</field>
        </record>
```

Part of the model I am using is the following:

```
class CarRequest(models.Model):
    _name = "car.request" # Table in DB => car_request
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _description = "Car Request"

    name = fields.Char(string="Request", required=True, )
    date_from = fields.Datetime(string="Starting Date", default=fields.Datetime.now(),)
    author_ids = fields.Many2many(
    'res.partner',
    string='Authors',
    track_visibility='onchange',
    )
```

Comment: Where do you define your action, `action_all_customers`? Is it in the same file or a different file? The action must be loaded before you reference it in you other view.